# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/parallels/chromium/_gclient_src_kz4Qr8'

Tags: python, git, chromium

When fetch the chromium source code follow the steps describe in 
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md
I was stuck at the fourth step:
`fetch --nohooks android`

The exception log:

> [0:35:17] Receiving objects:  51% (5417602/10525454), 1.24 GiB | 1.13 MiB/s
>   [0:35:18] Receiving objects:  51% (5458536/10525454), 1.24 GiB | 1.75 MiB/s
>   [0:35:19] Receiving objects:  51% (5463338/10525454), 1.24 GiB | 2.19 MiB/s
>   [0:35:30] Receiving objects:  51% (5471915/10525454), 1.24 GiB | 2.35 MiB/s
>   error: index-pack died of signal 90525454), 1.24 GiB | 202.00 KiB/s
>   [0:35:30] error: index-pack died of signal 9
>   fatal: index-pack failed
>   [0:35:30] fatal: index-pack failed
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_scm.py", line 906, in _Clone
>   print_stdout=print_stdout, stdout=stdout)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_scm.py", line 1210, in _Run
>   gclient_utils.CheckCallAndFilterAndHeader(cmd, env=env, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 314, in CheckCallAndFilterAndHeader
>   return CheckCallAndFilter(args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 576, in CheckCallAndFilter
>   rv, args, kwargs.get('cwd', None), None, None)
>
> ### CalledProcessError: Command 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git /home/parallels/chromium/_gclient_src_kz4Qr8' returned non-zero exit status 128 in /home/parallels/chromium
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2960, in 
>   sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2946, in main
>   return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
>   return command(parser, args[1:])
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2692, in CMDsync
>   ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1635, in RunOnDeps
>   work_queue.flush(revision_overrides, command, args, options=self._options)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 1075, in run
>   self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 977, in run
>   file_list)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_scm.py", line 130, in RunCommand
>   return getattr(self, command)(options, args, file_list)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_scm.py", line 419, in update
>   self._Clone(revision, url, options)
>   File "/home/parallels/depot/depot_tools/gclient_scm.py", line 914, in _Clone
>   if os.listdir(tmp_dir):
>   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/parallels/chromium/_gclient_src_kz4Qr8'

After search respective information on the internet, I can't find any useful help information.
**
Hope any one could help infer the real problem when fetch the chromium source code.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the reason is the same as others said, It because of the memory of system is small. after change the virtual machine's memory to 8 G. the problem was fixed.